# Can I use an Indian eVisa 6 months after its issuance date for a visit?

Tags: visas, india

My friend has been issued an eTV from India which is valid for one year with a multiple entry. The visa was issued in April 2019. However, he could not travel according to the planned dates.

The new travel date is set to be November 2019 which is 6 months after the date of issuing the visa. Would that be a problem at the immigration in India? Because I am aware of cases that, in different countries, they deny entry for those who did not activate their visas in due course.

Can you please advise on this?

Comment: Is it the first entry?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Yes it is the first entry, why?

Comment: depending on the visa, you cat get a stamp on first entry about the validity of visa for next entries, but it is not your case, if you have first entry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The e-visa itself specifies its validity period on its face. There is no such thing as "activation" nor any requirement to use the e-visa at any specific time, other than what is actually printed on the e-visa.

If the e-visa states:

> e-Visa Validity period is 365 days from the date of issuance of this ETA.

Then that is the actual truth.

---

You can [verify the status of your e-visa](https://indianvisaonline.gov.in/evisa/StatusEnquiry) at the official India e-visa web site.